# Speed Limit Detection Simulation in Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm actually developing a simulation for speed detection system in google maps version 3. I have been able to simulate moving the car between 2 coordinates. I have also defined a speed zone of lets say 40 km/h with two markers. what I need to do next is how to detect when the moving marker passes through the start of that speed zone and provide an alert that it has entered the zone and also an alert when it leaves the zone. Please help! I'm really stuck here! See my code below for further reference.

```
   // Declare variable map and marker
  var map, marker;
  // Set start position of car
  // Define coordinates in an array
  var startPosition = [-20.248685163166048, 57.68921500152305];
  // Set speed in km/h
  var speed = 35;

  // Set delay time in milliseconds
  /*
    If you set the delay below 1000ms and you go to another tab,
    the setTimeout function will wait to be the active tab again
    before running the code.
  */
  var delay = 100;

  // Define function animateMarker()
  // to animate the car between coordinates
  function animateMarker(marker, coords, km_h) {
      var target = 0;
      var km_h = km_h || 35;
      coords.push([startPosition[0], startPosition[1]]);

      // Define function goToPoint()
      // to go to a specified point/coordinate
      function goToPoint() {
        var latitude = marker.position.lat();
        var longitude = marker.position.lng();
        // Define step movement in metres
        var step = (km_h * 1000 * delay) / 3600000;

        var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[target][0], coords[target][1]);

        // Compute distance between marker and destination in metres
        var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(destination, marker.position);

        // Compute number of steps
        var numOfSteps = distance / step;
        var i = 0;
        var deltaLatitude = (coords[target][0] - latitude) / numOfSteps;
        var deltaLongitude = (coords[target][1] - longitude) / numOfSteps;

        // Define function moveMarker()
        // to move the marker
        function moveMarker() {
          latitude += deltaLatitude;
          longitude += deltaLongitude;
          i += step;

          if (i < distance) {
            marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));
            setTimeout(moveMarker, delay);
          } else {
            marker.setPosition(destination);
            target++;
            if (target == coords.length) {
              target = 0;
            }
            setTimeout(goToPoint, delay);
          }
        }
        moveMarker();
      }
    goToPoint();
  }

  // Define function initialize()
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.248685163166048, 57.68921500152305),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    var startPositionImage = 'images/markers/red_MarkerS.png';
    startPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.248685163166048, 57.68921500152305),
      map: map,
      icon: startPositionImage
    });

    var endPositionImage = 'images/markers/red_MarkerF.png';
    endPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.251659574520456, 57.684199270665204),
      map: map,
      icon: endPositionImage
    });

    var carImage = 'images/car/car-03-32.png';
    carMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(startPosition[0], startPosition[1]),
      map: map,
      icon: carImage,
      zIndex:9999
    });

    var speedLimitImage = 'images/speed-signs/speed-40.png';
    speedLimitStartMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.249944010457316, 57.6869901091452),
      map: map,
      icon: speedLimitImage
    });

    speedLimitEndMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.25161302114367, 57.68424151545719),
      map: map,
      icon: speedLimitImage
    });

    var alertImage = 'images/alert-signs/alert-03.png';
    alertMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.249267123751885, 57.68821371147283),
      map: map,
      icon: alertImage
    });

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
      animateMarker(carMarker, [
            // The coordinates of each point you want the marker to go to.
            // You don't need to specify the starting position again.
            [-20.248685163166048, 57.68921500152305],
            [-20.251659574520456, 57.684199270665204]
            ], speed);
    });
  }
  window.onload = initialize;
```

Comment: Use geofence to create a polygon which has entry and exit points (markers) and create alerts for when a user is entering and exiting the fence. Example here: https://github.com/hpneo/gmaps/blob/master/examples/geofences.html

Comment: Ok Sir. I'll consider the example above.